# Relationship between cookie and ip

Tags: cookies, ip

I use selenium to control a chrome browser from an Amazon ec2 node to log in a website using username and password and record the cookie info.

I found that I am able to use the same cookie to perform a login using selenium to that website from my mac.

Apparently my mac and and the ec2 node has different IPs.

So does this mean that I can use the cookie to perform a login from any host that has different ip? Is there any relationship between the cookie and the ip address?

Answer (score 0):

*So does this mean that I can use the cookie to perform a login from any host that has different ip?*

As long as there is no specific logic in server, **yes, you can**. Cookie-based login operation normally doesn't care which IP the client has.

*Is there any relationship between the cookie and the ip address?*

Yes. Cookie is part of HTTP protocol. HTTP is an application layer in TCP/IP protocol stack, which is based on TCP protocol (transport layer). Further more, TCP is based on IP protocol, which operates the IP address logic.

That is:

HTTP (application layer, include Cookie logic) --> TCP (transport layer) --> IP (network layer, include IP address logic)